# How to copy data from one table to another and then delete that data in first table using Java?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, oracle11g

Two tables are present in the database, one is Student table with columns roll_no(PK), name, grade and DOB, another table StudentLeft with columns roll_no, name, grade and leaving_date.

I want to delete the record of the student from Student table whose roll no is entered by the user, and add the roll no, name, grade and leaving_date (the date when the record is deleted and added to the table) to StudentLeft table.

This is my method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null, preparedStatement1 = null, preparedStatement2 = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String selectQuery = "", updateQuery = "", deleteQuery = "";

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int rollNo = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    try {
        selectQuery = "SELECT name, grade FROM Student WHERE roll_no = ?";
        updateQuery = "INSERT INTO StudentLog values WHERE roll_no = ?, name = ?, standard = ?";
        deleteQuery = "DELETE Student WHERE roll_no = ?";
        
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(selectQuery);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, rollNo);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        preparedStatement1 = connection.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
        preparedStatement1.setInt(1, rollNo);
        
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String name = resultSet.getString("name");
            String grade = resultSet.getString("grade");
            preparedStatement1.setString(2, name);
            preparedStatement1.setString(3, grade);
            preparedStatement1.addBatch();
        }
        preparedStatement1.executeBatch();
        preparedStatement2 = connection.prepareStatement(deleteQuery);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, rollNo);
        connection.commit();
    }

    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if (!preparedStatement.isClosed() || !preparedStatement1.isClosed() || !preparedStatement2.isClosed()) {
            preparedStatement.close();
            preparedStatement1.close();
            preparedStatement2.close();
        }

        if (!connection.isClosed())
            connection.close();
    }
    
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

These are the errors.

```
  java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00936: missing expression
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10500)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230)    
    at Q3.main(Q3.java:48)
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Q3.main(Q3.java:62)
```

I am using oracle 11g express database.

Comment: ok ... and what is(n't) working in your code? Can you be specific about what your problem is?

Comment: Can't understand properly what is the error. Showing two errors one in the execute batch and another in the area where I close the prepared statement.

Comment: edit your question and write there these errors

Comment: and you expect us to know what the error is, while you don't show us any information about what might go wrong, let alone an error message? You are printing your stacktraces (personally, I would put them in log files), so you should know exactly what goes wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've written can be simplified quite a bit:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        int rollNo = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);

            String transferStatement = "INSERT INTO StudentLog (roll_no, name, standard, leaving_date) " +
                    "SELECT roll_no, name, standard, SYSDATE FROM Student WHERE roll_no = ?";
            try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(transferStatement)) {
                stmt.setInt(1, rollNo);
                stmt.executeUpdate();
            }

            String deleteStatement = "DELETE FROM Student WHERE roll_no = ?";
            try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(deleteStatement)) {
                stmt.setInt(1, rollNo);
                stmt.executeUpdate();
            }

            connection.commit();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I've used try-with-resources statements, which simplifies the clean-up of connections and prepared statements: the connection and statements will get closed when the code inside the `try (...)` block finishes executing.

Transferring data from the `Student` table to the `StudentLog` table can be done in one go with an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement.  This statement doesn't return any result set: there's nothing to iterate through, we just execute it and the row gets inserted.

The `DELETE` statement is similar: it too returns no result set.  I've added the keyword `FROM` to it out of convention more than anything else: as pointed out on another answer, `FROM` is optional.

I've also moved the `catch (SQLException e)` block to the end: that will handle all SQLExceptions generated when connecting to the database or executing either of the prepared statements.

I've kept the code that attempts to load the Oracle database driver class, but added a `return` statement in the `catch` block: if there's an exception, the driver isn't on the classpath and connecting to the database is guaranteed to fail so we may as well stop.  However, for recent versions of the Oracle driver you don't need this check.  Experiment with it: see if the code works without this check and if so, remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't your query be

```
DELETE FROM Student WHERE roll_no = ?
```

instead of

```
DELETE Student WHERE roll_no = ?
```

Comment: Could you edit it to be more readable? Insert your sql's into code brackets

Comment: Though this should be re-phrased, this possibly is the solution the OP is looking for, so I have no idea why somebody would down-vote

Comment: execute will fail if query is wrong. I think that's the solution.

Comment: i did down voted it by mistake because i did read it the other way around. Sorry for that, i changed my vote already

Answer (score 0):

Your DELETE code used the wrong prepared statement, missing an execute.

It is advisable to use try-with-resources as below, for the automatic closing,
even on return or exception. (It also takes care of variable scopes.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    int rollNo = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    // Better statements possible.
    final String selectQuery = "SELECT name, grade FROM Student WHERE roll_no = ?";
    final String updateQuery =
        "INSERT INTO StudentLog VALUES WHERE roll_no = ?, name = ?, standard = ?";
    final String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM Student WHERE roll_no = ?";

    try { // Check whether you need this. It is for the old discovery mechanism.
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Database driver not provided", e);
    }

    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
                connection.prepareStatement(selectQuery)) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, rollNo);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
                try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement1 =
                        connection.prepareStatement(updateQuery)) {
                    preparedStatement1.setInt(1, rollNo);

                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        String name = resultSet.getString("name");
                        String grade = resultSet.getString("grade");
                        preparedStatement1.setString(2, name);
                        preparedStatement1.setString(3, grade);
                        preparedStatement1.addBatch();
                    }
                    preparedStatement1.executeBatch();
                }
            }
        }
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement2 =
                connection.prepareStatement(deleteQuery)) {
            preparedStatement2.setInt(1, rollNo); // NOT preparedStatement
            preparedStatement2.executeUpdate();
        }
        connection.commit();
    }
}
```

Then one should SELECT+INSERT to the database, using one statement (INSERT SELECT).

The SQL of the StudentLog is a bit incomprehensible to me, but a nice INSERT would be:

```
INSERT INTO StudentLog VALUES(roll_no, name, standard)
SELECT roll_no, name, grade
FROM Student
WHERE roll_no = ?
```

Removing the need java nesting of database accesses.

Comment: you missed the error in the DELETE, it should be DELETE FROM, instead of just DELETE

Comment: @Stultuske I added a FROM, the  [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8005.htm) tell FROM is optional. With FROM it is less terrifying.